# How do i set Environment Variables in my Flask - Nginx app running on GCPs compute engine (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-cloud-platform, spotify

I have a simple web app that has been deployed to a web server

**Now I've added a Spotify API which needs an access token**

**I'm using the spotipy library to make things easy.**

To authenticate i've set environment variables as mentioned in the *spotipy* docs.
The app is working just fine on my local machine, but it doesn't seem to fetch the environment variables on my ubuntu server (with Nginx).

i've tried setting them the same way, nothing seems to work

**how do set these variables in such manner that my "views.py" file picks them up just like my local machine**

Comment: Provide more details in your question on how you are launching your Flask application. This determines the `process` environment. Your logged in environment does not apply and that is why environment variables do not work. I do not recommend using environment variables. Either use a configuration file and read your parameters from there, or for secrets such as access tokens, use Google Secrets Manager or Cloud Storage.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks! 

I installed the "dot-env" library to handle environment variables from a .env file and it worked!

My guess is - on my local machine it was just picking up the variables from my Linux environment and not the venv that I had set up. But on the Nginx server it couldn't do the same because of the limitations I guess? 

I'm fairly new to web dev and cloud computing so I've been running into a lot of silly errors that takes me quite some time to solve. Appreciate your help!